# WPF ProgressBar Width not sizing to Text

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having an issue with the Microsoft WPF ProgressBar. I will set Width="Auto" and the width will size to the text width until a value property of ~97. Between values 97 and 100 the control will go exponentially larger until it hits MaxWidth.

The following style is setting the template for the ProgressBar. I can't seem to find anything that will cause it to behave until a Value of ~97. I do not touch the width in the code behind.

```
<Style x:Key="CurrentDayProgressBar"   TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="PART_Track" CornerRadius="2" Background="DarkGray" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" BorderThickness="1" />
                    <Border Name="PART_Indicator" CornerRadius="2" Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBarBackground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Name="PART_Text" Margin="2" Width="Auto" Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ProgressBar}, Path=Tag}" 
                               Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource SimpleTextBlock}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The first image below is what the bar looks like when it is at a Value of 99.2. The second is my implementation in the Telerik RadProgressBar, which behaves like I expect it to. The Telerik solution may be what I have to go with, but it would be nice to know why the Microsoft control is not working.

[WPF ProgressBar Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7OiZ.png)

[Telerik RadProgressBar and Textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74lqe.png)

Comment: I'm curious what the XAML looks like where this `ProgressBar` is used. It's in a `Grid` with a column width of `Auto`? Maybe you're looking for `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` combined with a reasonable `MinWidth`. If the `ProgressBar` implementation is indeed wonky (something I'm not sure about) perhaps you should make your own control that derives from `ProgressBar`, add a `Text` property instead of using `Tag`, and then maybe attempt to override the `MeasureOverride` method. It really seems like you shouldn't have to override that though.

Comment: Below is the item in the main window. It's in a Status bar, and pulled right. I can try the override. Maybe that will work.


`<StatusBarItem Padding="0" DockPanel.Dock="Right"  Margin="0,0,10,0">
                    <ProgressBar x:Name="TotalQuantityProgressBar"   Style="{DynamicResource CurrentDayProgressBar}" />
                </StatusBarItem>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PART_Track` cannot have any extra margins/borders attached to it and/or the `PART_Indicator` should be nested inside it. To resolve the problem you're having, do something like:

```
<Border CornerRadius="2" Background="DarkGray" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" BorderThickness="1" />
<Border x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="3">
    <Border Name="PART_Indicator" CornerRadius="2" Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBarBackground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Border>    
<TextBlock  ... />
```